# How to get access tokens for multiple resourceURL when using AAD v1.0

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I am evaluating use of the [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) plugin for use in our application.

We are using AAD v1.0 and need access tokens for multiple resources.

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#513-options-available-for-passportauthenticate) for the passport plugin, I only see an example for a single `resourceURL` and `accessToken`.

In the authentication configuration example:

```js
passport.authenticate(
  'azuread-openidconnect', 
  { 
    failureRedirect: '/', 
    session: false, 
    customState: 'my_state', 
    resourceURL: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send'
  }
);
```

And in the callback signature:

```js
function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {/* ... */}
```

Does passport-azure-ad support getting access tokens for multiple resources when using the v1.0 endpoints?